# How to concatinate two Fields in Display Member in Combobox C# from an OLEDB Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, oledb

I am new in OLEDB. I have a problem on displaying an Item on the combobox.

This is my code.

```
string strCon = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\database\database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";

        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string strSql = "SELECT * FROM Instructor";
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(strSql, conn));
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);

                cboInstructor.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                cboInstructor.DisplayMember = "LastName";
                cboInstructor.ValueMember = "ID";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Displaying one item in Combobox is working fine.
But I want to display concatinated Items on the combobox.

I tried something like this but i doesn't work.

```
cboInstructor.DisplayMember = "LastName,FirstName";
```

and

```
cboInstructor.DisplayMember = "LastName" + "," + "FirstName";
```

Also, on the Query I tried this.

```
string strSql = "SELECT ID, LastName + ', ' + FirstName  AS 'Name' FROM Instructor";

cboInstructor.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

I tried both but it Doesn't work. Please help me. I need to display or concatinate the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do it is create a class with what I want:

```
public class DisplayPerson
{
     public int ID {get;set;}
     public string FullName {get;set;}
}
```

Then I would create a List and use the datatable to populate it.  Then use the List to populate the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no C-progtrammer, so I cannot provide some snipplet.

Your SQL-Statement should work with
SELECT LastName + ',' + Firstname as Commonname FROM YourDB

be careful sometimes you should use & instead of + and " instead of '

The other way could be a calculated field:
1. add a new field to your table or dataset
2. select the oncalcfields event where you can calculate the value for the field like
newfield = firstname + ',' + lastname